# In Winsock/Win32, how to make recv() interruptible by ctrl-c without killing process?

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

Here's my attempt to create a wrapper around the winsock recv function in blocking mode so that a control-c can interrupt the connection without closing the process.

I get kind of stuck on how to do a "select" to detect if I have a "ctrl-C event" or a "socket recv event".

Any ideas on how to fix this code to get it working?  The idea is that, first I call the CtrlC_Init routine to install the ctrl-c handler... then I replace recv with CtrlC_Recv in my tcpip program, and finally, i  and press ctrl-c while tailing a file on a remote computer and it will magically stop without exiting my program....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

atomic<HANDLE> g_event_ctrlc {0};

BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType);

void CtrlC_Init()
{
    g_event_ctrlc = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(CtrlHandler, TRUE);
}
```

```
int CtrlC_Recv( SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags)
{
    WSAEVENT event_recv;
    HANDLE   handle_array[2];
    int      handle_count = 0;

    if (g_event_ctrlc != 0) {
        handle_array[handle_count] = g_event_ctrlc;
        handle_count++;
    }

    // Create Event Receive
    event_recv = WSACreateEvent();
    if (event_recv == WSA_INVALID_EVENT) {
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
    WSAEventSelect(s, event_recv, FD_READ | FD_CLOSE);
    handle_array[handle_count] = event_recv;
    handle_count++;

    DWORD rc = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(
                  handle_count,
                  handle_array,
                  FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE);

    // Close Event_Recv
    WSAEventSelect(s, event_recv, 0);
    CloseHandle(event_recv);

     // Check for Error
     if(rc == WAIT_FAILED) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        cout << "ERROR" <<  err << "\n";
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    // If Event Triggered
    if(rc >= WAIT_OBJECT_0 && rc < WAIT_OBJECT_0 + handle_count) {
        // Ctrl-C Interrupt Event
        if (g_event_ctrlc != 0) {
            if (handle_array[rc] == g_event_ctrlc) {
                 cout << "CTRL-C CloseSocket\n";
                 closesocket(s);
                 return SOCKET_ERROR;
            }
        }

        // Received Socket
        if (handle_array[rc] == event_recv) {
            return recv(s, buf, len, flags);
        }
    }

    return SOCKET_ERROR;
}
```

```
BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType)
{
    //NOTE: make sure console app is run from powershell.exe
    //   instead of being spawned by C++ IDE...
    //   some C++ IDEs trap Ctrl-C before it gets to console
    //   preventing this handler from getting triggered.
    if (fdwCtrlType == CTRL_C_EVENT) {
        printf("Ctrl-c\n");

        if (g_event_ctrlc != 0) {
            SetEvent(g_event_ctrlc);
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Since you are using `WSAEventSelect()` to wait on socket events, you need to use `WSACreateEvent()`, `WSASetEvent()`, and `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` instead. And there is no need to use `std::atomic` for `g_event_ctrlc`, as `CtrlC_Init()` should be called at program startup. And, since you are waiting on multiple network events on the socket, you should use `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()` to determine which event actually satisfied the wait, and to reset the socket state for the next wait (ie, don't call `WSAEventSelect()` on every read operation, call it only once when the socket is created).

Comment: you need use asynchronous I/O on socket if want have ability cancel operation.  `ConnectEx`, `WSARecv` instead `recv`, etc. with this you can initiate `closesocket` from any place (ctrl+c thread). but code will be too big, if not use some lib code

Comment: I got it on compile without needing to use WSAWaitForMultipleEvents... no idea if its valid code however..

Comment: Alun Jon, 2002 say:  from the documentation of WSACreateEvent(): "The WSACreateEvent function creates an event object that is manually reset with an initial state of nonsignaled. Windows Sockets 2 event objects are system objects in Windows environments. Therefore, if a Windows application desires auto reset events, it can call the native CreateEvent Windows function directly. "  **Since the Winsock events are nothing more than ordinary event objects on the
Windows environments, there is no functional difference between WSAWaitForMultipleEvents and WaitForMultipleObjectsEx.**

Comment: The WSA equivalents are designed for two purposes: 1. For support of Winsock on platforms other than Windows (Netware, for instance). 2. So that nobody tries to use CreateEvent() to make an automatic reset event
and use it with WSASelectEvent / WSAEnumNetworkEvents.

Comment: however if you not want/can not use asynchronous I/O - you can simply do all i/o (connect, send, recv) in single dedicated thread. for break this i/o you need have global access for this thread handle and call `CancelSynchronousIo(hThread)`. all. in any case any  `WSAEventSelect` never need

Comment: @Bimo that is an **implementation detail** that you should not rely on. Microsoft can always change the implementation in the future without breaking the API.